# using react hooks displaying data in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, redux

- I am trying to implement api call inside a function.
- so that I can pass the data directly inside the function on the page load.
- I am new to react hooks.
- I am getting this error when I include hooks 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:'
- basically I wanted to pass the data inside createData method
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet  and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o8wb4

demo.js

```or-tag-here
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  const channel = useSelector(state => state);

  console.log("before useEffect channel---->", channel);
  console.log("before useEffect channel.json---->", channel.json);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getPosts = channel => dispatch(fetchPosts(channel));

  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `createData` outside of a function component.
A quick fix is to move

```
  const initialRows = [
    createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
    createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
    createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
    createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
    createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
    createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
    createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
    createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
    createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
  ];
```

inside `EnhancedTable()`